# how to combine two column with keeping the same order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i want to combine two different columns in one column with keeping the same order like to start transfer the cells from the first column then cells from the second column.

appreciated any help

Comment: What have you tried?  Where have you run into problems.  Seems simple enough to select the cells from the second column; then paste them below the cells in the first column.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations of jumping to the top of the **Crappiest Question of the Week** list!

Comment: @Jeeped I'm sad that wasn't a hyperlink to a consolidated list :(

Comment: i'm trying to create a template which is used to consolidate two reports in one after generating the reports from third party administrators, and each report has a unique format, so i need a formula to copy the cells from the first report then to copy the cells from the second report with keeping the same order. i have used the below formula:=IF('Loss Ratio'!$F$5="NAS Pentacare",'NAS Claims'!A3,(IF(A2="0",'PC Claims'!E3))) so when i reach to row number 300 i need the formula to be: =IF('Loss Ratio'!$F$5="NAS Pentacare",'NAS Claims'!A303,(IF(A303="0",'PC Claims'!E3))), and then E4, E5 and go on

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in columns A and B, use the below formula,

```
=IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A),INDEX(A:A,ROW()),INDEX(B:B,ROW()-COUNTA(A:A)))
```

[image]

Alter the formula per your needs.